# Как при перезагрузке страницы сохранить выбранный option?

Tags: javascript, vue3

Всем добрый, помогите пожалуйста решить задачу, нужно чтобы выбранный option сохранялся в select после перезагрузки страницы или редиректе. Мои полномочия закончились на данном этапе, я потратил дни на поиск решения и практику, пока ничего не получается. Код я набросал в песочнице:

https://replit.com/@teplandrey41/SkinnyCadetbluePrinter#src/components/ParentComponent.vue

В проекте select много, я для наглядности вывел один. Все select генерятся в массиве allPanels. Буду невероятно благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Чтобы сохранялось - надо где-то сохранять: куки, localstorage, websql/indexedDb и пр.

Comment: Я сохраняю весь массив в localstorage и там же я сохраняю выбранный value. С самим текстом option не могу разобраться, как сохранять правильно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка в том что ваш компонент `BaseSelect` не был верно привязан к modelValue, из-за чего возникала данная проблема:

Ваш вариант был следующим:

```
<select @change="selectChanged"> <!-- Поле select не знает о том что у него уже есть данные -->
  <option disabled selected>{{ label }}</option>
  <option
    v-for="(option, index) in options" 
    :key="index"
    :value="option.value"
    :selected="option.value === modelValue"
  >
    {{ option.text }}
  </option>
</select>
```

И еще одно замечание по следующей строчке кода:

```
:selected="option.value === modelValue"
```

Данная проверка не будет корректно работать, так как в localStorage оно у вас хранится как строка (`string`), а в options как число (`number`)

В общем, чтобы исправить вашу проблему, нужно всего лишь указать `value` для поля (в нашем случае `select`), ну и убрать аттрибут `:selected`, так как проверять уже на соответствие не нужно, браузер сам автоматически это будет делать исходя от `:value` самого поля `select`.

```
<select :value="modelValue" @change="selectChanged">
  <option disabled selected>{{ label }}</option>
  <option
    v-for="(option, index) in options" 
    :key="index" 
    :value="option.value" 
  >
    {{ option.text }}
  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Всё работает, спасибо огромное за то, что уделили время и помогли решить задачу. Я действительно несколько дней потратил на поиск проблемы в других компонентах, видимо матчасти не хватило. Вам хорошей рабочей недели)